# Declaration of Structure for link list

Tags: c

```
typedef struct
{
    int idno;
    char name[max];
    float cgpa;
}student;

struct node
{
    student s;
    Link  next;
};
 typedef struct node Node;
 typedef  Node  *Link;
```

This doesnot work since compiler doesn't know about Link, but this works

In function 'main':|
error: unknown type name 'Link'|

```
typedef struct {
    int idno;
    char name[max];
    float cgpa;
}student;

typedef struct node Node;
typedef  Node  *Link;
struct node
{
    student s;
    Link  next;
};
```

But here how does compiler knows before structure declaration and hence one could have them type defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
typedef struct node Node;
```

tells the compiler that there is a structure type with the tag `node` defined somewhere, and that `Node` is another name for that type.

```
typedef  Node  *Link;
```

tells the compiler that `Link` is another name for `struct node *`. Since all pointers to structure types are required to have the same representation and alignment requirements, that is all the compiler needs to know to use it in

```
struct node
{
    student s;
    Link next;
};
```

Comment: upvoting because it is correct, but I think it is much less confusing to just say `struct node{node* next;}`

Comment: Did you mean `struct node { student s; Node *next; };` or `struct node { student s; struct node *next; };`? I would prefer either to hiding the pointer in the `typedef Node *Link;` too. I understood the question as the OP wanting to have explained why it works when the typedefs are given before they are used, and thus stuck to the OP's code.

Comment: good call, my forthcoming bad answer will be completely tangential!

Answer (score 0):

from the C std:

> A typedef declaration does not introduce a new type, only a synonym
>   for the type so specified.

The C std doesn't seem to mention if the typedef can occur after it is used... My suspicion is that this not standard C, but a byproduct of a 2 pass compiler...

**and now for the critique and ramblings section of the answer:**

here are a couple of questions to ask yourself:

1) are students reusable

2) do nodes cary extra information that isn't in student...

lets assume that `student`s are reusable, that is they can exist in more than one list...
now `node` can not contain a whole `student`, because if you change one you don't change them all...

```
typedef struct
{
    int idno;
    char name[max];
    float cgpa;
}student;

typedef struct
{
    student * s;
    node * next;
}node;
```

`Link` is a bad name for `node *`, `node *` is a very good name that you will get used to reading, or if you must `node_ptr`.

If there is only one list and the `node`s don't contain anything extra (not in `student`)
then you can put the links in student:

```
typedef struct
{
    int idno;
    char name[max];
    float cgpa;
    student * next;
    student * prev; //if you want to be doubly linked
}student;
```